Will my employment in any shape or form be jeopardized if I ask for recommendation letters for MsC?
I'm aiming for OMSCS (GaTechs online master's degree). I've been with the current company for 6 months. Attempted to reach out to undergrad professors but they don't remember me well enough to positively recommend me.

Please expand acronyms. The world doesn't know what "OMSCS", "BsC" and "MsC" are.

@PhilipKendall Thanks, I edited it.

If the degree dovetails with the company's area, it probably would be ok; otherwise not.  I'd use caution.

@JosephDoggie Same field. I'm a SWE and aiming for part time master's.

You need to ask your colleagues. Some companies are very supportive of part-time degrees. And some are less so. It could depend on your manager also. For instance, your company could be supportive, but your manager may be unwilling for you divide your time like that. We really can't answer your question.

This really depends on the company.
Larger companies may in fact offer education benefits which would give you some time off for study, or repay part of your tuition, as long as the degree is in a field that is of value to them. But you need to ask what your employer's process is for that. Simply asking that question should not have an adverse effect on your career unless they really want only low-education employees. You can ask coworkers unofficially, to find out whether they think there's any risk in raising the question with your manager.
(Note that the answer may be "we need your full attention on the job right now; ask again next semester.")
